# Cant figure out "cannot be provided without an @provides-annotated method" error

Tags: android, dependency-injection, interface, compiler-errors, dagger-2

This is driving me crazy. I can't seem to figure what is the problem with this.

**Code:**

```
public interface IMinutesCounter {
    void startTimer();

    void stopTimer();
}
```

**and implementation:**

```
public class MinutesMonitor implements IMinutesCounter {
    private ITimerCallback timerCallback;

    @Inject
    public MinutesMonitor(ITimerCallback timerCallback) {
        this.timerCallback = timerCallback;
    }

    void startTimer(){...}

    void stopTimer(){...}
}
```

`CallAlarm` implementing `ITimerCallback`

```
public class CallAlarm implements MinutesMonitor.ITimerCallback {

    @Inject
    public IMinutesCounter minutesMonitor;


    public CallAlarm (HealthService context) {
        this.minutesMonitor = minutesMonitor;
       ....
    }
}
```

As you can see, `IMinutesCounter` needs a `MinutesMonitor.ITimerCallback`.

**What I want is - ** From the `CallAlarm` class (implementing `MinutesMonitor.ITimerCallback`)**inject** myself (`this`) to instantiate the `IMinutesCounter`.

**Dagger 2 part:**

```
@Module
public class CallAlarmModule {

    IMinutesCounter.ITimerCallback timerCallBack;


    public CallAlarmModule(IMinutesCounter.ITimerCallback timerCallBack) {
        this.timerCallBack = timerCallBack;
    }

    @Provides
    public IMinutesCounter.ITimerCallback provideCallAlarm() {
        return timerCallBack;
    }
}
```

**and:**

```
@Component(modules = CallAlarmModule.class)
public interface CallAlarmComponent {
    void injectTimerCallback(IMinutesCounter.ITimerCallback service);
}
```

it gives me

> error: IMinutesCounter cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.

Answer (score 0):

This means that dagger does not know what a `IMinutesCounter` is or where to get one.

While dagger knows about `MinutesMonitor` and can construct it using constructor injection, you don't specify what to use for `IMinutesCounter`.

You can just remove the interface and just depend on `MinutesMonitor`, but I'm guessing that you actually want to use the interface and its implementation, for which you will have to *provide* the implementation, as the error suggests.

In your module add something like the following

```
@SomeScope // maybe add some scope
@Provides
public IMinutesCounter provideMinutesCounter(MinutesMonitor monitor) {
    return monitor;
}
```

This snippet makes use of constructor injection. It says *to provide a `IMinuteCounter` I need a `MinutesMonitor`—its implementation.* You then just return the implementation, and dagger will be able to use your implementation where the interface is requested.

```
@SomeScope // maybe add some scope
@Provides
public IMinutesCounter provideMinutesCounter(/* MM dependencies */) {
    return new MinutesMonitor(/* MM dependencies */);
}
```

The same could be done by just creating the object yourself, but I guess you see why just using constructor injection makes things easier.

Comment: thanks for your answer. if I change the variable in CallAlarm to be MinutesMonitor like you said, I get same error but about ITimerCallback -"ITimerCallback cannot be provided without an Provides- or Produces-annotated method", and then, if I change in the MinutesMonitor the constructor to accept "CallAlarm" instead of  "ITimerCallback" -> I get "dependency cycle" error

Comment: @OfekAgmon yes, that's the same issue, again, with the interface not being found. You should probably provide your interfaces, and not rely on your implementation, as shown in the 2 code samples below. the cycle is a whole other issue, for which there is no _easy_ solution, you can read about it if you just search for `[dagger-2] cyclic` or `[dagger-2] cycle` here on SO

Comment: I added the first snippet you posted, and left the other code as is - I still have the same error, cant provide IMinutesCounter

Comment: @DavidMedejak, isn't this case like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052261/using-dagger-2-to-inject-into-service ? your answer over there worked great and this issue looks the same, having an object that needs to instantiate another object with himself as a parameter. though, when I tried to apply  the code from the other answer, it gave me the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily fix this with the following additional line:

```
@Module
public class CallAlarmModule {
    @Provides
    public IMinutesCounter minutesCounter(MinutesCounter minutesCounter) {
        return minutesCounter;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Also, your `CallAlarm` doesn't actually receive a `minutesMonitor` even though it should in its constructor

Comment: I added it, now it says "cant provide ITimerCallback"

Comment: please look at the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052261/using-dagger-2-to-inject-into-service. its about injecting a service from the service's OnCreate (this) into the class he is dependent on. isn't this the same?

Comment: ....I can't really tell, the code that makes your question not work is not included here.

Comment: please see my new question here, see if you know what's the problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075951/dagger-2-cant-figure-out-how-to-inject-myself-this-into-class-without-depende

Answer (score 0):

```
@Inject
public IMinutesCounter minutesMonitor;
```

change to

```
@Inject
public MinutesCounter minutesMonitor;
```

cause your interface can't be injected.