# How to provide database to MyFirebaseMessagingService using Dagger 2 so that I can store fcm message locally in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, dagger-2

How can I make it possible to pass database Instance to the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class which extends `FirebaseMessagingService` so that I can save `data` payload locally?

Note: I already setup dagger 2 in my app, it's working perfectly.

Below is `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService @Inject constructor(exampleOneDao: ExampleOneDao?) : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    //need db instance to store data payload locally (Room)
    }
}
```

And below is the `AppModule` class of Dagger 2

```
@Module(includes = arrayOf(ViewModelModule::class))
class AppModule() {

    // --- DATABASE INJECTION ---
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideDatabase(application: Application): MyDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(application,
               MyDatabase::class.java, "MyDatabase.db")
              .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideExampleOneDao(database: MyDatabase): ExampleOneDao {
        return database.exampleOneDao()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideMyFirebaseMessagingService(exampleOneDao: 
        ExampleOneDao): MyFirebaseMessagingService {
           return MyFirebaseMessagingService(exampleOneDao)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to provide database and dao to `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class?

I tried above method to provide `exampleOneDao` to the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class, but it throws the following `Exception`

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.user.app.firebase.messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService> has no zero argument constructor
```

Thank You.

Comment: why would it not be possible? Did you even try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but It was throwing instantiation exception. Going to update the posted code with the method I tried but have no success

Comment: @TimCastelijns I updated the code above which I tried.

Comment: You cannot use constructor injection because you do not control the service lifecycle. You can use field injection however

Comment: How can I perform field injection? can you please provide the code example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052261/using-dagger-2-to-inject-into-service

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the example in above link, can you please provide some example related to the code which I posted?

Comment: no. Do it yourself. There are plenty of examples to find on this subject

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TimCastelijns thank you for motivating me to search for the solution, I end up with the great solution and had a great learning curve.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Finally got the solution from this link: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/253

As `MyFirebaseMessagingService` is a `Service` class, so for injection in `Service` class, Dagger provides a way through which we can inject dependencies into Service class. Below are the steps to enable injection in service class:

**1) Make Application implements HasServiceInjector and inject a DispatchingAndroidInjector for services.**

```
public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector, HasServiceInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingActivityInjector;

    // Add this line
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service> dispatchingServiceInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppInjector.init(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingActivityInjector;
    }

    // override this method after implementing HasServiceInjector
    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Service> serviceInjector() {
        return dispatchingServiceInjector;
    }

}
```

**2) Create a new module to perform injection over your services.**

```
@Module
abstract class ServiceBuilderModule {

    // for my case, the service class which needs injection is MyFirebaseMessagingService
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MyFirebaseMessagingService contributeMyFirebaseMessagingService();

}
```

**3) Register your new module in your application's component.**

```
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        ActivityBuilderModule.class,
        // Need to define previously created module class here
        ServiceBuilderModule.class
})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(App application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
    void inject(App app);
}
```

**4) And finally, override method onCreate of the service adding AndroidInjection.inject(this).**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    //So now we are able to inject here same as we do in Activity. No need for constructor injection
    @Inject ExampleOneDao exampleOneDao

    // Override this method first
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // use your dao here to store remoteMessage data payload into your database, e.g exampleOneDao.save(somethingHere)
    }


}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Kotlin, it triggers the error No injector factory bound for Class<com.fuentesoft.messagingapp.service.MessageService>. Injector factories were bound for supertypes of com.fuentesoft.messagingapp.service.MessageService: [com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService]. Did you mean to bind an injector factory for the subtype?

Comment: @MijaelViricochea This is because you need to set an injector factory i.e. you need to tell the Injector that this service class is one of the injection targets. You can do this by creating a new module class like:

```
@Module
abstract class ServiceModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [])
    internal abstract fun bindService(): MessageService
}
```

And make sure to include ServiceModule when you declare the component. This error will disappear then.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Kotlin implementation:

Application.kt

```
class MyApplication: Application, HasServiceInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingServiceInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service>

    override fun serviceInjector(): AndroidInjector<Service> {
        return dispatchingServiceInjector
    }
}
```

Module.kt

```
@Module
abstract class FirebaseServiceModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeMyFirebaseMessengingService(): MyFirebaseMessengingService
}
```

Component.kt

```
@Component(modules = [FirebaseServiceModule::class])
interface Component {
    ...
}
```

MyFirebaseMessengingService.kt

```
override fun onCreate() {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate()
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `override fun serviceInjector()`

Comment: the application needs to extend [`HasServiceInjector`](https://dagger.dev/api/2.23.1/dagger/android/HasServiceInjector.html)

Answer (score 0):

**The injection of dependencies with Dagger into services has to be through public class variables and not from the constructor** to avoid type error *MyFirebaseMessagingService has no zero argument constructor*.

After implementing the [solution](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/253#issuecomment-352210847) pass

From:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService @Inject constructor(exampleOneDao: ExampleOneDao?) : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    //need db instance to store data payload locally (Room)
    }
}
```

To:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    @Inject 
    lateinit var exampleOneDao: ExampleOneDao

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    //need db instance to store data payload locally (Room)
    }
}
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51026168/5279996)

Comment: Just a small correction.
Injected variables cannot be private.